# Terraform: using ${path.module} in a module does not point to module directory

Tags: aws-lambda, module, terraform, terraform-template-file

I have a repo with my terraform module where i create a zip file using archive file which i then use as a filesource for a lambda

```
data "archive_file" "example" {
  type        = "zip"
  output_path = "./files/example.zip"

  source {
    content  = templatefile("${path.module}/files/example.py", {})
    filename = "example.py"
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "example_lambda" {
  filename         = data.archive_file.example.output_path
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.example.output_base64sha256
  etc...
}
```

And in this repo example.py file exists and the file path is ./files/example.zip

Then in my project repo i call the module:

```
module "my_example_module" {
  source                         = "git::https://github.com/my-module-repo"
  project_name                   = var.project_name
  etc...
}
```

But when i try to apply this it will error saying it can't find the zip file but i think it is looking in my project's directory rather than the module's directory:

```
module.example.aws_lambda_function.example_lambda: Creating...

Error: reading ZIP file (./files/example.zip): open ./files/example.zip: no such file or directory
```

Is ${path.module} not correct to use here? How do i get the terraform apply to look in the module for the zip file?

I tried hard typing the path just to see if it would get past the error but don't think i was putting in the right path to a directory in a module - would it be like `module.my_example_module../files/example.py`?

**EDIT**

So i think i understand the problem a bit more now. I changed the code a bit so the output path uses path.module:

```
data "archive_file" "example" {
  type        = "zip"
  output_path = "${path.module}/files/example.zip"

  source {
    content  = templatefile("${path.module}/files/example.py", {})
    filename = "example.py"
  }
}
```

and now when i call the module in my project it is looking for the path: `".terraform/modules/my_example_module/files/example.zip"` which is correct.

but then because the lambda function in the module is set to use the `output_path`  from the data archive block it will also look in  `".terraform/modules/my_example_module/files/example.zip"`  in the module repo which wouldn't exist (unless terraform just creates this these directories if they don't already exist?)

So now the question is, how do I:

- Have my project, where i call the module, look for `".terraform/modules/my_example_module/files/example.zip"`
- But then have the module just look for `./files/example.zip`

My project file structure is:

```
project
│   README.md   
│
└───terraform
│   └───files
│       │   lambda.tf
│       │   main.tf
│       │   ...
```

Comment: This error message would be the lambda resource throwing, and therefore the error is not with your usage of `path.module`. If the path to the file was incorrect or it did not exist, then TF would immediately throw an error from the usage of `templatefile`. You would need to attack this from the direction of the lambda being unable to find the file instead.

Comment: @MattSchuchard thanks for the comment. I looked into it more off your comment and added an edit my original post. Think im in a position where i am calling the filepath to the module correctly, but then in the module itself i am not entering the correct path. But unsure how to separate the 2

Comment: Please provide the directory tree of your project.

Comment: @Marcin updated and added my post with file structure

Comment: @polo you can have an empty (dummy) zip in the same directory and when you run plan and apply subsequently it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it turned out that the reason was due to the fact I am running my terraform jobs via a pipeline and the plan and approve stages are separate jobs. Sorry i didn't include this information in original post but it didn't cross my mind at all that it was related to the pipeline

Archive provider will create the zip file at the plan stage for some reason and not apply and there for the zip file was not being passed between the jobs.

Here is the discussion for this problem and some workarounds included here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-archive/issues/39

Answer (score 1):

I used a pipeline for running the terraform plan and apply job with an approval gate and I was facing a similar issue.

this worked for me: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-archive/issues/39#issuecomment-815021702

```
data "archive_file" "zip" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "${path.module}/textfile.txt"
  output_path = "${path.module}/myfile-${random_string.r.result}.zip"
}

resource "random_string" "r" {
  length  = 16
  special = false
}
```